# top bar in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I based my application with the default "Page-based App" in Xcode. I'm trying to display a navigation bar on top of my DataViewController in my storyboard without using a navigation controller. The problem is, when I swipe left and right, the navigation bar seems to go along with the gesture. How can I make it "not-movable"?

Things I tried:

- Putting the navigation bar in my RootViewController instead. When I simulate the app, the navigation bar is not visible.

EDIT:
RootViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

GJDataViewController *startingViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:0 storyboard:self.storyboard];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

self.pageViewController.dataSource = self.modelController;

[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

// Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 40.0, 40.0);
}
self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
}
```

DataViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];
}
```

Comment: show your Implement code

Comment: @NitinGohel kindly see my edited question. the code basically is the same with the "Page-based Application" in xcode. For my version, I only added a navigation bar and buttons in my storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Use your 2nd trial: "Putting the navigation bar in my RootViewController instead." to make navigation-bar immovable with every age transition.
2. Now in RootViewController.m, change the line `CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;` to `CGRect pageViewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, 64, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-64);` .Where 64=20(status-bar height) + 44(navigation-bar) height.

2nd step will adjust frame of your DataViewController's view below added navigation-bar in RootViewController and thus navigation-bar will not hide.

Hope, it helps you....Happy Coding! :-)